# Converting a modeler 2.x to a 3.x - Done by hand

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

After reading here that's no easy way to convert a modeler in 2.18 to 3.10, (model to model3).

I made my model3 by hand based on the model version 2 i had. After some problems with the OUTPUT files, i finally was able to run all algoritm.

But now, all the layers that came as output (and with no errors on the Log) they come always with 0 features.

Basically i do for 5 layers
v.clean Break -> Delete duplicates -> Count Points
And from all i can see in the log, QGIS actually do the all the steps, but the output come out with ZERO features

Comment: But count points doesn't return any features, only a number?

Comment: Count is just one of the algorithm I use, a number to a field on a layer that is created on the modeler! My problem is, the modeler doesn’t return any features, but return the layers! 
At first I had errors on the log, output layer problems and others. Now, I have no errors, the log run just smoothly, but the outputs come out with zero features within! I basically copy/paste my modeler from 2.18 to 3.10 qgis! Works just fine in 2

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems, the output layers need to be .gpkg. On shp, every output layer comes with zero featurees.

Problem solved. By defaulting on the modeler the output path with gpkg extension.

The main problem was the v.clean (break) function, that return zero features after run, so all the output afterward were empty.